# Are Scheduled Reminders broken regarding event participant status?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

Using Civi 4.6.18 we have a scheduled reminder set up that should be sending an email to people who have registered for a particular event, opted to pay later, but who have yet to make the payment. A fairly common scenario I'd guess.

I have the checkbox ticked to record an activity when the reminder gets sent.

Using Advanced Search I can see that at this point I have three people that meet the criteria to receive the reminder.

In this case I have manually added two additional contacts who should also receive the reminder.

Cron fires, scheduled job runs, nothing gets recorded in the CiviCRM log or the PHP error log, the manually added additional contacts have an activity record suggesting that an email was sent, but the three who met the criteria for the reminder have no activity recorded.

What it looks like from this is that the reminder is working in so far as the manually added contacts are being sent the email, but the reminder is not succeeding in finding the three criteria driven contacts.

Anyone else seeing this type of issue? I can see that are a good number of issues in relation to Scheduled Reminders not doing what they are supposed to, but I couldn't spot anything in relation particularly to event participation status.

Comment: I setup a reminder in this exact scenario just the other day and it worked as it should in version 4.6.19. If you search on that payment status do all the records expected come up?

Comment: I did some further work on this, setting up some test reminders using the same criteria, showed that the reminders were getting sent and recorded as activities, as expected. I still don't know what the issue was with this reminder, but I can't replicate it.